# KDE: Meta+[number] doesn't launch [number]th application Task Manager ("start bar")

Tags: kde, kde5

My Task Manager (panel at bottom of screen that uses the "Icon-only Task Manager widget") looks like this:
[image: KDE Task Manager widget with three applications pinned — from the left: Firefox, Qutebrowser and Konsole (the default KDE terminal)]
When I press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, I expect Firefox will be launched — this is not the case.
However <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> works — it launches Qutebrowser.
And then <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> doesn't work again.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is to make sure the "**Activate Task Manager Entry [number]**" (eg. 1) action (shortcut entry) in **System Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts > Shortcuts** (use the searchbar) is bound.

[image: KDE shortcut settings showing that the shortcut action Activate Task Manager Entry 1 is unbound, explaining why the Meta+1 shortcut is not working]

This was happening to me because in the past I rebound Meta+1 in **Custom Shortcuts** to use [jumpapp](http://ttps://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp) (eg. Meta+1 launches or focuses Firefox regardless if it's first or 2nd in Task Manager). That unbound Meta+1 from "Activate Task Manager Entry" because Meta+1 was used elsewhere.